# How can I select a clip/slip/strip under the cursor(=timeline-indicator) via the keyboard?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, shortcut

I want to be able to do the simplest of editing (scroll through timeline, make cut, select clip, remove clip, go on) while not needing to grab the mouse, therefore only using the keyboard as input.

So far I have:
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> play forwards
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> play backwards (very slow for me)
<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> move, 1 frame at a time
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd> move, 10 frames at a time (configurable)
<kbd>K</kbd> split clip in two at the current location
**<kbd>???</kbd> select clip at the current location**
<kbd>X</kbd> delete selected clip(s)

One can select a clip with <kbd>RMB</kbd>, which is bound to the "clip.select" function the shortcut editor. Adding a new keyboard-shortcut for "clip.select" did not work for me.
I found multiple candidates for what I want to do, but unfortunately none of them worked out:

"Strips to the right / left" seems to select all clips in the same row, and its not clear how it works (to the left/right of what? For some reason, not the timeline-indicator)
"Select more/less" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>-</kbd>) seems to always start at the right, therefore I cannot select a clip which is between two other clips.

PS: It is possible to (re-)bind any item available in menus to a keyboard-shortcut by <kbd>RMB</kbd> on the respective item, but I have not found a matching one.

Info:
Blender 2.79b
Windows